# Problem When I try to use Case statement in JPQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpql

Hello I am trying to implement the query (which contains case statement) from database department but I could not figure it out what the problem is.

```
@Query("select new com.withgratitude.api.core.domain.ReportTopTenBiddersTable( CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName), " +
           "b.auctionId, b.date), " +
           " case when (b.isTheWinner = 0) then 'No' when (b.isTheWinner = 1) then 'Yes' else 'No Winner' end as winnerBid" +
           "                        from Bids b, Users u " +
           "                       where b.userId = u.userId " +
           "                       order by CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName)")
   List<ReportTopTenBiddersTable> reportTopTenBiddersTable();
```

```
Here is the Query I am trying to implement:
#top 10 bidders - table
select CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name, b.auction_id, b.date, 
                              case b.is_thewinner when 0 then 'No' when 1 then 'Yes' end as WinnerBid, b.offer
                       from bids b, users u 
                       where b.user_id = u.user_id
                       order by name
                       limit 10;
```

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 130 [select new com.withgratitude.api.core.domain.ReportTopTenBiddersTable( CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName), b.auctionId, b.date),  case when b.isTheWinner = 0 then 'No' when b.isTheWinner = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No Winner' end as winnerBid                        from com.withgratitude.api.core.dao.Bids b, com.withgratitude.api.core.dao.Users u                        where b.userId = u.userId                        order by CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName)]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
... 83 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of problems here - one of them is the return type (a list of ReportTopTenBiddersTable objects), which seemingly leaves no place for the full bid information.

The parts don't fit (there's sql mixed with jpql), the types don't align - but it's hard to tell from this short example what's the source of the errors - and the best solution.

One of the simplest solutions would be to add the bid information to the ReportTopTenBiddersTable object; this way you can remove the `case` (but still retain the data) and keep the signature intact:

- change the constructor `ReportTopTenBiddersTable` to accept a "Bid" object (and store it in a field).
- change the constructor call at beginning of the query to include `b` (you can leave out the date because it's accessible from `b` anyway):

```
  select new com.withgratitude.api.core.domain.ReportTopTenBiddersTable(
      CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName), b.auctionId, b.date) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Andronicus answer, I guess you can use `nativeQuery` and write your database request in plain SQL.

```
@Query(value = "select CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name, b.auction_id, b.date, " +
        "case b.is_thewinner when 0 then 'No' when 1 then 'Yes' end as WinnerBid, b.offer " +
        "from bids b, users u " +
        "where b.user_id = u.user_id " +
        "order by name " +
        "limit 10", nativeQuery = true)
List<ReportTopTenBiddersTable> reportTopTenBiddersTable();
```